# How can I for loop data in chart js with vue js

Tags: vue.js, charts

I want to for loop the labels and data so I'll never use this again `labels: [this.transaction_per_day[0].Day...` and `data: [this.transaction_per_day[0].Amount...`. I just realized when the user transacts on the next day, the data will not show in the bar graph. The problem is when I change the index into `i` inside the bracket instead of `0,1,2,3`. It only displays the first index which is the `0`. Can somebody help regarding my problem? Here's my code

```
 retrieveTransactionPerDay : function() {
        var self = this

        axios.post(this.urlRoot + this.api + "retrieve_transaction_per_day.php")
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            vm.transaction_per_day = response.data
            for(var i = 0; i < this.transaction_per_day.length; i++) {

                var ctxChart = self.$refs.myChart.getContext('2d')

                var myChart = new Chart(ctxChart, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: [this.transaction_per_day[0].Day, this.transaction_per_day[1].Day, this.transaction_per_day[2].Day, this.transaction_per_day[3].Day],
                        datasets: [{
                        label: 'Transaction per day',
                        data: [this.transaction_per_day[0].Amount, this.transaction_per_day[1].Amount, this.transaction_per_day[2].Amount, this.transaction_per_day[3].Amount],
                        backgroundColor: [

                           'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                           'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                           'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                           'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'  
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                           'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                           'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                           'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                           'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'                      
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    title : {
                        display : true,
                        text : "TRANSACTION GRAPH",
                        fontFamily: "sans-serif",
                        fontSize: 18
                    },
                }
            });
        }
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the for loop and use `Array.map` to get the label and data

```
vm.transaction_per_day = response.data
var myChart = new Chart(ctxChart, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: vm.transaction_per_day.map(item => item.Day),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Transaction per day',
      data: vm.transaction_per_day.map(item => item.Amount),
      backgroundColor: [

        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "TRANSACTION GRAPH",
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
      fontSize: 18
    },
  }
});
```